# How to handle errors thrown by render2 in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

I'm working on this and can't think of a way to handle the error thrown by **renderer2.selectRootElement**. 
This is what my function looks like:

```
private doSomeAnimation(){
 const modalWrapper = this.renderer2.selectRootElement('.modal-wrapper', true);//It fails here
 // finally do something with modalWrapper
   this.renderer2.addClass(modalWrapper, 'fade-out');
}
```

and if I open the console I see this error:

```
global-angular-error-handler.service.ts:49 Error: The selector ".modal-wrapper" did not match any elements 
at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (dom_renderer.ts:146) 
at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animation_renderer.ts:156)
at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (services.ts:762)
at ModalComponent.animateClosing (modal.component.ts:39)
....
```

I also looked at the Docs for Renderer2 and **selectRootElement** looks like this

```
selectRootElement(selectOrNode: string|any):any{
  let el: any = typeof selectOrNode === 'string'? document.querySelector(selectOrNode) : selectOrNode;
  if(!el){
    throw new Error(`The selector "${selectorOrNode}" did not match any elements`);
  }
  el.textContent = '';
  return el; 
}
```

As you can see my code **fails** in line number 1 of my function, so my question is **how to NOT show any error in the console** if there wasn't any match. I mean how to not show this message in the console

> `"The selector ".modal-wrapper" did not match any elements"`

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could wrap the `selectRootElement` call into a try catch.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera can you post your solution? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the call into a try/catch

```
let modalWrapper;
try {
    modalWrapper = this.renderer2.selectRootElement('.modal-wrapper', true);
} catch (e) {
    // do what you need to do with the exception here.
    return;
}
```